# NDSolve Problems with Cardiovascular Modeling

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to use 27 simultaneous differential equations to model the cardiovascular system. I have the following code, however, the output isn't giving interpolating functions, but rather another rearrangement in terms of NDSolve. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Please, don't ask a new question -- you can edit your old one. And also don't use images -- post properly formatted code.

Comment: Ok. However, I do not know how to fix or edit the code, and format it properly.

Comment: I see that you are using square brackets as parentheses. Square brackets should only be used for function calls. If you are starting programming in a new programming language you're supposed to read up a bit about basic syntax, you should not be guessing it.

Comment: In the upper right corner of the question edit box there is a help button, marked with a question mark.

Comment: You also use curly brackets as parenthesis. Again, you cannot use arbitrary symbols as you like in a programming language. They may have a predefined function other than what you think they have.

Comment: Note that Sjoerd's comment about square brackets is what someone else tried to say on your other question in a more cryptic way (the comment about machine precision). Might be good to make that connection, so you can understand that comment as well.

Answer (score 2):

It would help a lot if you write each of the equations separately and name them appropriately; e.g. `eq1`, `eq2`, `eq3`... etc. Then you can use `NDSolve` routine to try and solve the system (along with the boundary/initial conditions).

Also, try formatting your code properly so that the stack-exchange community can help you more easily. From a quick view of the picture above, it seems that Mathematica does not recognize as equations those arguments that you have. Try avoiding the use of subscripts (you can type `f0` instead of $f_0$). Always use parentheses instead of arbitrary symbols (curly brackets etc.), as Sjoerd C. de Vries correctly pointed out in his comment.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still correcting the code. However, one question. When you say to type in f0 instead of the subscript, do you mean in Mathematica as well? Or just on StackExchange? Thank you so much

Comment: I mean in Mathematica. On SE use pre-formatted input for code and modify it when applicable.

Comment: Ok, so I did what you said.... but it still gives me the equation rearranged. Are the parameters right? And it says to use an argument?

Comment: It could be easier to understand the problem if you copy-paste the mathematica code here and the messages that you get. And of course, use the pre-formatted method for inputing code. It makes it much more readable and in this case it is easier for more people to get involved and help you.